# Masstransit - how to use custom activities

Tags: .net, masstransit

Documentation states that custom activities should be used when

> the complexity is best encapsulated in a separate class rather than
> being part of the state machine itself

https://masstransit-project.com/usage/sagas/automatonymous.html#custom

My question is, what you should and absolutely should NOT do in the activity? For example, should I be making HTTP calls? e.g

```
public async Task Execute(BehaviorContext<OrderState, SubmitOrder> context, Behavior<OrderState, SubmitOrder> next)
    {
        //make an http call, possibly store the result in the saga instance.
        **var result = await _httpclient.getAsync(myUrl);**

        // call the next activity in the behavior
        await next.Execute(context).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
```

I came across multiple scenarios where saga receives an initial event and then needs to retrieve some more data in order to proceed. How should this be handled? Looking for some recommendations, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, making these types of requests (such as HTTP) is not recommended. Sagas execute within the context of a database transaction, and for that reason adding an external dependency, such as a slow or perhaps unavailable HTTP resource can cause the concurrency throughput to drop significantly if sagas are blocked waiting on external systems.

It might be better to have a separate consumer responsible for querying the remote system, and send/publish a command from the saga which the consumer would use to retrieve the data and report it back to the saga (either via a response, or an event observed by the saga).

The concurrency mode doesn't matter. For instance, if the saga is waiting on an HTTP request, and optimistic concurrency is used, if another event updates the saga while the current event is waiting on an HTTP response, when the saga tries to persist it would fail due to a concurrency/version conflict as it was updated by the other event.

So, when it comes to sagas, short and sweet should be the goal, delegating all the heavy lifting to other components. Sagas should orchestration work, and not do too much work themselves.

Comment: Thank you for the insightful response, it was very helpful. I see that you are leaving the choice between publishing and sending up for decision. If a saga needs to fetch some data like in the example and only one consumer would be interested in this event, wouldn't it make sense to use a request for this specifically?

Comment: Yes, I would use Request, and let it publish the message, the response of which would then be correlated back to the state machine instance.